# Python3 look for characters in a list and remove/add space

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

I have a list and I'm trying to look through each item for specific characters and remove any white space before and after it (if any) and then add a space after the character. My attempts in coding this have failed miserably so i have written some sudo code so that it hopefully makes more sense.

```
check_char = ":.,"

list = [
    'This : is;a:string. yep!.'
    'This,is another , string']

for item in list:
    # Look for character(s) in check_char
    # remove white space before and after character
    # add space after the character
```

Comment: could you explicitly specify the expected output?

Comment: You can use re module, or a more complicated for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could work:

```
import re

check_char = ":.,"

list = [
    'This : is;a:string. yep!.',
    'This,is another , string']

for item in list:
    splitted = re.split("(:|\.|,)", item)
    stripped = [x.strip() for x in splitted]
    whitespace = [x + ' ' if x in check_char else x for x in stripped]
    joined = ''.join(whitespace)
    print(joined)
```

Some very useful help found here: http://programmaticallyspeaking.com/split-on-separator-but-keep-the-separator-in-python.html

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using regular expressions, specifically [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub), to find any matches to whitespaces with your chars in between, and replacing them with just the char and a single space, like this:

```py
import re

check_char = ":.,"
regex_pattern = r'\s*(:|\.|,)\s*'

list = [
    'This : is;a:string. yep!.',
    'This,is another , string']

result = [re.sub(regex_pattern, r'\1 ', item) for item in list]
print(result)
```

Output: `['This: is;a: string. yep!. ', 'This, is another, string']`